# How do I compute the electron reflection using the non-equilibrium Green's function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, condensed-matter

I can compute the electron transmission $T(E)$ from source to drain through a transistor using the equation

$$T(E) = tr[\Gamma_1(E)G(E)\Gamma_2(E)G^\dagger(E)]$$

where $G(E)$ is the retarded Green's function and $\Gamma_1(E)$ and $\Gamma_2(E)$ are functions of the source and drain self-energies.

I'd like to know how to compute the reflection coefficient $R(E)$. I know I could just assume unitarity and use the relation

$$R(E) = 1-T(E)$$

But I want to compute $R(E)$ directly (for testing purposes).